# I'm trying to use visual force to dynamically filter a report, first filter criteria passes in, others 3 don't

Tags: apex-code

Customer Circuits  - What are the associated active customer circuits?

Answer (score 0):

try to edit your report set three filter criteria and save it. then try to pass your criteria values again. i think the trick is to let the report expect three parameters.